Could not remove duplicates from the excel, duplicates removing from only one column but not from the other column
I am trying to remove duplicates from a dataset in excel which has 700k rows with 10 columns. I am trying to remove duplicates from the first row which has ID. Rest of the columns has data associated with this ID. when am trying to remove duplicates by using the Data Tools> Remove duplicates> on ID column it is deleting only the duplicates in ID column but not the other columns.
I tried using remove duplicates from data tools in excel. I have 700k rows with 10 columns filled with data. i tried removing duplicates based on the first column value and I tried using remove duplicates option as I mentioned earlier It is removing duplicates in the column alone not the other column. Hence the count in the first column reduced to 600k and the other column count remains 700k.

When you use the Remove Duplicates in the Data tab, you need to expand the selection when Excel prompts you, as seen in the image below;

